# Is there a reason not to use Pressflow instead of Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, pressflow

When building a Drupal 6 site (mysql+php5), are there any reasons not to use Pressflow on the production server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing that should explicitly stop you from doing so. However there are some things that may be worth considering.

- There are less developers working on
  pressflow and there may be a loger
  time to get core bugs fixed. Also
  there are less people using it so
  more chance of finding an
  undiscovered bug.
- While pressflow is API compatible,
  most modules are not tested against
  pressflow so a particular module may
  not work with pressflow.
- Security fixes may take longer to get
  into pressflow than Drupal core.
- It is potentially more difficult to
  configure as there are settings aimed
  at high end performance.

Finally I suppose I would turn round the question, unless you have a website with *a lot* of load, why would you use a distribution aimed at high traffic sites. A lot of the scalability gains in pressflow have been back ported from D7, so you may consider that as well.

Note, I don’t have anything against pressflow, I have used it and it has worked well and the people who work on it are very clever. I am just pointing out general risks with using a less popular branch.

Comment: Anothing to add, is the upgrade from Presflow D6, to D7 is more difficult, since there are issues in the upgrade path which is made from D6.